# Python: re module to replace value in dictionary

Tags: python, regex

I started looking at the handy `re` module available in Python today, and hoping I could get help with `re.sub`

My file:

```
avid "Av.Id
fated "fEIt.Id
leaded "lEd.Id
wicked "wIk.Id
```

I want to sub if match `"(v|t|d|k)\.Id"` then change to `"\.(v|t|d|k)Id"` so that output looks like:

```
avid "A.vId
fated "fEI.tId
leaded "lE.dId
wicked "wI.kId
```

I could match my string fine with `re.search` however I'm stuck at how I can do the actual replacement when the letter is different every time (v, t, d, k, etc).  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use `".$1Id"` as your replace string

Answer (score 1):

Use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) and reference the saved group `(v|t|d|k)` using `\g<1>` syntax:

```
import re

PATTERN = re.compile('(v|t|d|k)\.Id')
with open('input.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print PATTERN.sub(".\g<1>Id", line)
```

It prints:

```
avid "A.vId
fated "fEI.tId
leaded "lE.dId
wicked "wI.kId
```